# rpi4 - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS - NFS drive not mounting on boot

Tags: 20.04, mount, fstab, raspberrypi, nfs

I have been having an issue getting an NFS share to automatically mount on boot for a handful of rpi4's all running Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS.

If I run a `sudo mount -a` the drive successfully mounts with no issues.

I have tried a variety of fstab options with no success. Below is the current config:

`192.168.1.100:/mnt/media   /mnt/media   nfs    _netdev,auto,nfsvers=4   0  0`

Running `sudo cat /var/log/syslog | grep nfs` returns the following:

> Jun 24 18:59:01 test-01 kernel: [    7.865019] Installing knfsd
> (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).
>
> Jun 24 18:59:01 test-01 systemd[1]: nfs-config.service:
> Succeeded.
>
> Jun 24 18:59:03 test-01 kernel: [   18.820306] FS-Cache: Netfs
> 'nfs' registered for caching
>
> Jun 24 18:59:03 test-01 mount[1754]: mount.nfs: Network is
> unreachable

I am not sure if it is trying to mount before the network is online, but i thought the _netdev option prevented this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem with cifs (smb) too.

The solution for me was to add several options to mount:

- `x-systemd.automount`
- `x-systemd.mount-timeout=5`
- `x-systemd.device-timeout=5`

Try this one if it works for you:

```
192.168.1.100:/mnt/media   /mnt/media   nfs    x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.mount-timeout=5,x-systemd.device-timeout=5,_netdev,auto,nfsvers=4   0  0
```

But before you reboot your system check if the mount procedure works with: `mount -a`. If this command does not mount, the code above wont help. If `mount -a` gives any error, you should remove the added fields, otherwise you might run into problems after reboot.

Comment: Added the options you listed and am still able to mount -a with no errors (and the drive shows up) but it is still not adding at boot.  
Since adding those options the log seems to have dropped the error about the network:  
```Jun 24 20:08:52 test-01 kernel: [    7.892317] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).  
Jun 24 20:08:52 test-01 systemd[1]: nfs-config.service: Succeeded.```

Comment: you can try to increase the timeout. if that does not work, i am sorry, that i cannot help.

Comment: No dice. Increased the timeouts to various settings and still wont mount on boot (but still mounts with ```mount -a```  
Log is showing something different now though  
```Jun 25 13:02:25 test-01 kernel: [58797.261249] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching  
Jun 25 13:04:00 test-01 blkmapd[931]: open pipe file /run/rpc_pipefs/nfs/blocklayout failed: No such file or directory  
Jun 25 13:04:00 test-01 kernel: [    7.864061] Installing knfsd (copyright (C) 1996 okir@monad.swb.de).  
Jun 25 13:04:00 test-01 systemd[1]: nfs-config.service: Succeeded.```

Answer (score 0):

My solution for the same problem on RaspberryPi OS 11 was to run this:

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Comment: on the client or server

Comment: This gave `Failed to enable unit: Unit file NetworkManager-wait-online.service does not exist.`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same command in my Ubuntu 22.04 and it solved the problem

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

Answer (score 0):

Got an issue with

```
systemctl enable NetworkManager-wait-online.service
```

This gave me

> Failed to enable unit: Unit file NetworkManager-wait-online.service does not exist.

It was resolved with

```
sudo apt install network-manager
```